# Sufficient conditions for monotonicity with probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X_i$ be a continuous non-negative real-valued random variable and $i=1,...,n$. $X_i$ are not necessarily independent over $i$. Let $b>0$, $\delta>0$. Consider 
$$
A_n:=\operatorname{Pr}\left(\delta\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>b\right)
$$
Do you know some sufficient conditions on the distribution of each $X_i$ such that $A_n$ is monotone increasing (decreasing) in $n$ when $\delta>0$ ($\delta<0$)?

Comment: The random variables are all nonnegative?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: But it is always increasing in $n$.

Comment: Why? Independently of $\delta$? Can you give me an intuition for that or, better, a proof?

Comment: Sums of non-negative numbers can never decrease with $n$

Comment: $A_n$ is a probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_n$ is increasing in $n$ because the event
$$
\bigg\{ \delta \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i > b \bigg\}
$$
is a subset of the event
$$
\bigg\{ \delta \sum_{i=1}^n X_i > b \bigg\},
$$
simply because $X_n$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Independently of the sign of delta?

Comment: No, a negative $\delta$ reverses everything: larger $n$ reduces $A_n$.

Comment: If $\delta<0$, then $\delta\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le 0 < b$ and so the probability in question is $0$. (If $\delta$ and $b$ are both negative, then yes, $A_n$ is decreasing in $n$.)